# I cant use the variable in a different script (unity 2D). Any suggestions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

i want to use variables levelButtons and levelunlocked from the script below :-

```
public class LevelSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
public Button[] levelButtons;
private void Start()
 {
    int levelunlocked = 1;
    int levelReached = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelReached", levelunlocked);
    for (int i = 0; i < levelButtons.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i + 1 > levelReached)
        {
            levelButtons[i].interactable = false;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

and use them in this script below. it would be a huge help.

```
public class Level : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] int breakableBlocks;  
SceneLoader sceneloader;

private void Start()
{
    sceneloader = FindObjectOfType<SceneLoader>();
}

public void CountBreakableBlocks()
{
    breakableBlocks++;
}

public void BlockDestroyed()
 {
    breakableBlocks--;
    if (breakableBlocks <= 0)
    { 
        sceneloader.LoadWinScreen();
    }
 }
}
```

any ideas?? its unity c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `levelunlocked` and `levelReached` outside of the `Start` method and make them public, like this:

```
public class LevelSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button[] levelButtons;
    public int levelunlocked = 1;
    public int levelReached;
    private void Start()
    {
        levelReached = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelReached", levelunlocked);
        for (int i = 0; i < levelButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 > levelReached)
            {
                levelButtons[i].interactable = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then to access `levelunlocked` and `levelReached`, get a reference to `LevelSelector` by using `GetComponent`, or make the fields static and access them by doing `LevelSelector.levelunlocked` or `LevelSelector.levelReached`.

Comment: no problem ;) Also I would not recommend to make fields static just to access them! What if there are multiple of those components? (Though ofcourse unlikely in this case but still it is very unclean.) Rather I would extend a bit the `GetComponent` part or simply mention that you could add a `public LevelSelector` and reference the according component in the inspector ;)